# How to use Fluent Assertions to test for exception in inequality tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, nunit, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to write a unit test for a greater than overridden operator using Fluent Assertions in C#. The greater than operator in this class is supposed to throw an exception if either of the objects are null.

Usually when using Fluent Assertions, I would use a lambda expression to put the method into an action. I would then run the action and use `action.ShouldThrow<Exception>`. However, I can't figure out how to put an operator into a lambda expression.

I would rather not use NUnit's `Assert.Throws()`, the `Throws` Constraint, or the `[ExpectedException]` attribute for consistencies sake.

Comment: See https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#exceptions

Comment: That link is already dead. Right now it's changed to https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/ but Kote's answer should steer anyone coming later correctly.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You may try this approach.

```
[Test]
public void GreaterThan_NullAsRhs_ThrowsException()
{
    var lhs = new ClassWithOverriddenOperator();
    var rhs = (ClassWithOverriddenOperator) null;

    Action comparison = () => { var res = lhs > rhs; };

    comparison.Should().Throw<Exception>();
}
```

It doesn't look neat enough. But it works.

Or in two lines

```
Func<bool> compare = () => lhs > rhs;
Action act = () => compare();
```

Comment: `act.Should().NotThrow();` to check for not exceptions.

Comment: I used it slightly different for my problem because I was testing an async method. So for async/await you can replace Action to Func<Task>

Answer (score 0):

you can use Invoking too

```
 comparison.Invoking(()=> {var res = lhs > rhs;})
.Should().Throw<Exception>();
```

more  information is [here](https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to write this would be something like this:

```
var value1 = ...;
var value2 = ...;

value1.Invoking(x => x > value2)
.Should().ThrowExactly<MyException>()
.WithMessage(MyException.DefaultMessage);
```